# Outlook add-in versions

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am using the Outlook API (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets). At the moment it is on 1.6 and I see some changes towards a 1.7 (I think).

- What versions of Outlook support the current 1.6 version? (What is the oldest version supporting it). I saw some versioning for Excel and Word, not Outlook though.
- And is it clear when the new update will become available?

Comment: The URL is of the Word API (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets), correct Outlook URL: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Any specific reason why are you interested in build number?

Comment: In order to advise customers. In general I am not assume which patch level the customers are. I hope that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement set 1.6 APIs are supported starting with build number 16.0.9020.2000. We don't have preset timeline for the requirement set 1.7 APIs, it will be released when all supported platforms implement all the APIs from that set. That work is currently in progress, that's why you may see some APIs from 1.7 in preview.